# Regex to enclose objects in an array

Tags: javascript

I have lots of files containing many calls to a specific method which used to accept objects but now requires an array.
I would like to use Notepad++ to find/replace all of these calls with the required array.

Here's an example:

```
attach({ name: 'filename', url: 'fileURL' })
```

This needs to be converted to:

```
attach([{ name: 'filename', url: 'fileURL' }])
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You'd like a regex for a find/replace notepad++ operation?

Comment: That's correct, it would take way too long to do it all manually or even file by file.

Comment: Not sure what exact regex "flavor" NotePad++ uses and I don't have it installed here to test, but a very basic expression should probably do - escape the ( and ), and add grouping for the inner part - `attach\(({ name: '.*?', url: '.*?' })\)` https://regex101.com/r/AUavhF/1

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Just curious, why can't you replace `({` with `([{` and then `})` with `}])`?

Comment: There are other functions which use objects which should not be replaced with arrays unfortunately, or I would have gone with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd search for:

```
attach\((.+)\)
```

and replace it with

```
attach([$1])
```

This will capture everything between attach's parentheses and adds a pair of square brackets around it.

edit: Older versions of notepad++ use `\1` instead of `$1` to refer to the 1st captured group.

Comment: This worked perfectly, the only thing I had to change was the replacement, adding a \ before the ( and ).